# Prove by induction the inequality

Tags: calculus, proof-writing, induction, solution-verification

> Prove by induction that: $$n^n > (n+1)^{n-1}$$

My atempt so far (I don't know if I'm following the right path):

Base case is trivial: $1^1 \geq 2^0 = 1$

For $p(n) \Rightarrow p(n+1)$:

$$(n+1)^n> n^n > (n+1)^{n-1}$$
$$(n+1)^{n+1} > (n+1)^n$$

I'm stuck with this and can't figure out how to get the right side to be $(n+2)^n$.

Comment: I think you have a typo in the last line of the inductive hypothesis, you should to write $(n+1)^{n+1}>((n+1)+1)^{(n+1)-1}$.

Comment: Frankly calculus is a much better option

Comment: As an aside, although this is likely beyond the scope of what you are expected to know it is worth mentioning that $(n+1)^{n-1}$ is the number of [parking functions](https://www.math.tamu.edu/~cyan/Files/Yan-Final-Own-Copy.pdf) and the probability that a collection of $n$ cars with independent uniformly distributed preferred spaces successfully park is as a result $\dfrac{(n+1)^{n-1}}{n^n}$ which noting that this is a probability and coupled with the observation that it is possible the cars do not successfully park proves the result you are interested in.

Comment: @JMoravitz That's interesting! I didn't know that.